# How to set HTML data attributes inside render in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, custom-data-attribute

I want to set my data attributes inside the `render()` in React (specifically while using `map()`).

Here is what I want to happen:

```
let ownDataAttribute = 'data-foo'
...
render() {
    return (
    <>
    {
        array.map(item => <div [ownDataAttribute]="foobar" >{item.name}</div>
    }
    </>)
}
```

One solution I thought of is:

```
let ownDataAttribute= "foo"

array.map(item => {
    let div = document.createElement('div')
    div.dataset[ownDataAttribute] = "foobar"

    // other code follows
})
```

However, I find that the solution too tedious. Is there a solution that would be similar to the first snippet shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass each key-value pair as props.

```
// your attributes
const myAttributes = {
  ownDataAttribute: 'data-foo',
  otherAttributes: 'others'
}

array.map(item => (
  <div
    {...myAttributes} // all key-value pair are passed as prop
  >
    {item.name}
  </div>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, the below code uses [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
   array.map(item => {
   let attr[ownDataAttribute] = "foobar";
      return <div {...attr} >{item.name}</div>
   })
```